# Ninepatch Drawable with ColorFilter

Tags: android, nine-patch, android-drawable, porter-duff, statelistdrawable

I'm create some calendar view and what I want to do is to create a background for a LineairLayout that is clickabe.

Therefore I create a StateListDrawable with two images:

1. The image for the background
2. The image when the item has been pressed

So far that works with this piece of code:

```
    NinePatchDrawable background = (NinePatchDrawable) context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.calendar_item);
    Drawable backgroundFocus = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.calendar_focus);

    int stateFocused = android.R.attr.state_focused;
    int statePressed = android.R.attr.state_pressed;

    StateListDrawable sld = new StateListDrawable();
    sld.addState(new int[]{ stateFocused,  statePressed}, backgroundFocus);
    sld.addState(new int[]{-stateFocused,  statePressed}, backgroundFocus);
    sld.addState(new int[]{-stateFocused}, background);
    return sld;
```

But I would like to do something extra. I'dd like the user to be able to pass in a color that he wants to use to display the background. So the background var must be variable, but it must be based on the nine-patch drawable.

So I thought I could just do something like this:

```
background.setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN);
```

Where Color.RED must be replaced by the color of choice of the user.

But that doesn't seem to be working. The nine-patch is created perfectly but without the color fiilter being applied.

I also tried other PoterDuff.Mode 's:

- SRC
- SRC_ATOP
- DST_IN
- ...

If you have any clue what I'm doing wrong or what I could do else to solve my issue please let me know! :-)

Kr,

Dirk

Comment: AFAIK statelists remove all colorfilters attached to the drawables. So the problem maybe isn't the 9patch part, it maybe is the statelist.
Could you please test to remove the statelist ,apply the colorfilter to the drawable and give feedback?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can assign ColorFilters for each Drawable in a StateListDrawable. Reason: The ColorFilter will be removed/replaced when the StateListDrawable changes state. To see this in action, change the order of the statements such that:

```
background.setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN);
```

comes after the creation of the StateListDrawable. You'll see that the ColorFilter IS applied. But, as soon as the state changes(click, then release), the ColorFilter isn't there any more.

StateListDrawables allow you to set a ColorFilter: `StateListDrawable#setColorFilter(ColorFilter)`. This is how the supplied (or null) ColorFilter is used:

**StateListDrawable#onStateChange(int[])**:

```
@Override
protected boolean onStateChange(int[] stateSet) {
    ....
    if (selectDrawable(idx)) {    // DrawableContainer#selectDrawable(int)
        return true;
    }
    ....
}
```

**DrawableContainer#selectDrawable(int)**:

```
public boolean selectDrawable(int idx) {
    ....
    if (idx >= 0 && idx < mDrawableContainerState.mNumChildren) {
        Drawable d = mDrawableContainerState.mDrawables[idx];
        mCurrDrawable = d;
        mCurIndex = idx;

        if (d != null) {
            ....

            // So, at this stage, any ColorFilter you might have supplied
            // to `d` will be replaced by the ColorFilter you
            // supplied to the StateListDrawable, or `null`
            // if you didn't supply any.                 
            d.setColorFilter(mColorFilter);

            ....
        }
    } else {
        ....
    }
}
```

**Workaround**:

If at all a possible, use an ImageView (match_parent for dimensions) for visual communication. Set the StateListDrawable that you've created as the ImageView's background. Create another StateListDrawable for the overlay:

```
StateListDrawable sldOverlay = new StateListDrawable();

// Match Colors with states (and ultimately, Drawables)
sldOverlay.addState(new int[] { statePressed }, 
                         new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

sldOverlay.addState(new int[] { -statePressed }, 
                         new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#50000000")));

// Drawable that you already have
iv1.setBackground(sld);

// Drawable that you just created
iv1.setImageDrawable(sldOverlay);
```

Another possibility: use a FrameLayout in place of LinearLayout. LinearLayouts do not have a foreground property.

```
// StateListDrawable
frameLayout.setBackground(sld);

// For tint
frameLayout.setForeground(sldOverlay);
```

It does involve overdraw, making it a sub-optimal solution/workaround. Perhaps you can look at extending StateListDrawable and DrawableContainer. And since you are not using a ColorFilter for the StateListDrawable, you can remove `d.setColorFilter(mColorFilter);` from overridden `DrawableContainer#selectDrawable(int)`.

Comment: Hmmm... I'll have to ponder those. While I am not the original asker of the question, it does neatly cover a scenario I was presented in an office hours chat and found interesting. Being able to pick a color at runtime to apply to a nine-patch pretty much requires a `ColorFilter` AFAIK, though I am far from expert in this particular corner of Android. The `StateListDrawable` is because in many cases this nine-patch would be applied to something that ought to be a clickable element. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @CommonsWare `... this nine-patch would be applied to something that ought to be a clickable element` - It's bit of a surprise that `StateListDrawable` is implemented this way. `ColorFilters` for individual Drawables passed as an additional argument to `StateListDrawable#addState()` would have offered more control/choice. Or, a null-check before setting/overwriting the ColorFilter for individual Drawables with a ColorFilter set _on_ the `StateListDrawable` itself would have worked too. Well, could-have, should-have, `extends` ...